# How do I lay out figures that need to be both regular and sideways?

Tags: graphics, floats, rotating

I'm submitting to a conference with limited page space and need to fit my figures all on one page.  The layout needs to look like the following:
[image]

I've figured out how to turn a figure sideways, but I can't figure out how to specify to place the figures in a bottom right under the top fig and next to the sideways fig.

Comment: Do you need captions under each figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do need captions for each figure, you can use `subcaption` and `minipage` to achieve the desired output.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,rotating}
\usepackage{mwe} % for images and lipsum

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{image}
    \caption{Subfigure 1}
  \end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{sideways}
      \includegraphics[height=\textwidth]{image-a}
    \end{sideways}
    \caption{Subfigure 2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-b}
      \caption{Subfigure 3}
    \end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-c}
      \caption{Subfigure 4}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Caption for all four figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: this is great, but I do need captions for each one.  Is there a reason I can't caption normally here?

Comment: @jbbj94: Then you'll need to add the `subcaption` package. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: @jbbj94: Normally only one caption is allowed in each `figure` environment. To have multiple captions, you'll need to introduce the `subfigure` environment within a `figure`. Then the `subcaption` package will allow you to add subcaptions to each figure.